# incorrect Vector.size() returned

Tags: java, graph, vector

I'm implementing a Graph which holds "Book" objects as its nodes. The nodes are connected if the books share a keyword. The keywords for each book are held in a Vector within the Book class. To do this, I've created 3 classes.

1) Books 2) Vertex 3) Graph

The Vertex class holds the Book object and also has a Vector containing all the other Vertex objects (other books which share a keyword). In the Driver, I create the book, pass it to a Graph which then inserts it into a Vertex and finally the Vertex into a Vector named "bookGraph".

```
public final class Graph {

    private Vector<Vertex> bookGraph = new Vector<Vertex>();
    private int bookCounter = 0;

    public Graph() {

}

public void addBook(Book bk) {
    Vertex vtx = new Vertex(bk);

    bookGraph.add(vtx);
    bookCounter++;

    System.out.println("Book #1 has " + bookGraph.get(0).getBook().getKeywords().size() + " keywords");

    // addAdjVertices();

}

public void showKeywords() {

    System.out.println("Book #1 is " + bookGraph.get(0).getBook().getKeywords().size() + " keywords");

}
```

The information from the books are read from a file in the Driver and inserted into a book object. I'm trying to make sure that this information is read in correctly and properly inserted into the Graph. My problem occurs when trying to get the size of the keyword Vector within the "showKeywords()" method in the Graph class. bookGraph.get(0).getBook().getKeywords().size() returns 0 when the exact same command in the addBook() method returns the correct size. I've implemented accessor methods such as getTitle() or getAuthor() in the Book class and those work correctly within the showKeywords() method. The keyword vector seems to be the only issue within the showKeywords() method. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my Driver class....

```
  boolean fileopen = false;
  String title, author, keys;
  long isbn_number;
  Vector<String> keywords = new Vector<String>();
  String filename = "books.txt";
  String[] keywordTokens;
  Scanner fin = null;
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
  Graph books = new Graph();

  try {
   fin = new Scanner (new FileReader(filename));
   String fline;

   fileopen = true;

   System.out.println("Reading books.txt...");

   while (fin.hasNextLine()) {

    fline = fin.nextLine();
    title = fline;
    fline = fin.nextLine();
    author = fline;
    fline = fin.nextLine();
    isbn_number = Long.parseLong(fline);
    fline = fin.nextLine();
    keywordTokens = fline.split(",");

    for (int x = 0; x < keywordTokens.length; x++) {
     keywords.add(keywordTokens[x]);
    }

    Book tempBook = new Book(title,author,isbn_number,keywords);
    books.addBook(tempBook);
    keywords.clear();

    if (fin.hasNextLine()) fline = fin.nextLine();


   }

   books.showKeywords();   
   System.out.println("Ready.");
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
 }
```

Comment: not an answer to your question, but consider using ArrayList

Comment: Vector was suggested by my instructor initially but he left the choice to us in the end. I decided to with his suggestion. What advantage does ArrayList offer? Thanks.

Comment: ArrayList performs a little better because it's not synchronized. It also implements more interfaces, so there are more handy ways to work with it.

Comment: That leads me to wonder how up-to-date your instructor's knowledge is, to be honest...

Comment: Please see my edited answer - it's a problem in your "driver" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like it should work - there's nothing obviously wrong (like accidentally using static variables). Can you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? The error is likely to be somewhere else - are you calling `setKeywords(new Vector<String>())` somewhere, for example?

Any reason for using `Vector` rather than the more common `ArrayList` by the way? I would also suggest that `setKeywords(String key)` should probably be called `addKeyword` instead...

EDIT: Okay, now that you've posted the code it's obvious: you're only ever creating a single instance of `Vector`. You're then reusing that instance for every line, and clearing it at the end.

Just declare your keywords variable *inside* the loop, create a new instance on every iteration, and don't clear it afterwards.

To make your code as readable as possible (and avoid this sort of thing) I would suggest you declare every variable at the point of first use wherever possible, with the narrowest possible scope.

Comment: Ah, ArrayList didn't used to be more common.  Back when I was a nipper when Java was 1.0 Vector was all we had and we were grateful ;-)  I think back then it was called Vector to make C++ migrators a bit happier.

Comment: I've not yet used any instances of the setKeywords() method. No static variables anywhere either. Not sure what the most appropriate way to paste in my driver would be as I'm only allowed 600 characters here.

Comment: @Vahe: Edit your question instead... but cut the sample code down as much as possible, so it's really short. You may well find that in doing so, you discover the problem yourself.

Comment: Edited my original post and added the Driver. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this snippet and check whether the error is still there:

```
public void test() {
  Vector<String> keywords = new Vector<String>();
  keywords.add("keyword");
  Book bk = new Book("Author", "Title", 12345, keywords);

  Graph bookGraph = new Graph();
  bookGraph.addBook(bk);
  bookGraph.showKeywords();
}
```

Comment: This works when I insert it into Graph.java. However, attempting the same thing from my Driver class results in the original error.

Comment: To elaborate, I inserted this snippet into Graph.java. Then called it via books.test(). (books being a Graph object).

Comment: So now you're sure that the problem is not related to Vector#size and that it is in another part of your application, maybe even inside you Driver class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got lost in your graph of objects :) I suggest to use [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) to determine how your code should behave and to make sure it actually does behave the way you expect. The tests can build small examples and then check the various getters to see whether they return the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

For what do you need the copy constructor Book(Book)? Perhaps you put copies of the books instead of the books itself into your collection?